# AWS SQS Send Message java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, sdk, amazon-sqs

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeSendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1813)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1795)
    at com.tvg.atp.orch.utils.SoapUtil.sendErrorString(SoapUtil.java:700)
    at com.tvg.atp.orch.handler.OrchFunction.apply(OrchFunction.java:73)
    at com.tvg.atp.orch.controller.OrchController.processEvent(OrchController.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I'm relatively new to gradle. I am sending a message to an AWS SQS Dead letter queue. I keep getting the error above. The same class first attempts to pass the message to another queue based on a filter and if that is unsuccessful the message is sent to the dlq. I've tested the happy path and it works. The error string is generated but sending the message to the dlq doesn't work. I've read that this is most commonly a conflict with sdk's but I haven't been able to resolve it. This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        SPRING_BOOT = '2.2.12.RELEASE'
        SPRING_CLOUD_AWS = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
        SPRING_CLOUD = 'Hoxton.SR8'
        AWS_SDK = "1.11.611"
        SPRING_BOOT_GRADLE_PLUGIN='2.4.0'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${SPRING_BOOT}"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
        classpath "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:6.1.0"
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.27.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.21'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version '0.21'
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.0.0"
}

configurations {
    antJUnit
}
dependencies {
    antJUnit 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.10.8'
}


apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

group = "com.group.${rootProject.name}"
archivesBaseName = "${rootProject.name}"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//mainClassName = 'com.group.notifications.handler.ScheduledEventHandlerImplementation'
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${SPRING_BOOT}"
        dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${SPRING_BOOT}"
        //dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:${SPRING_BOOT}"
        
        dependency 'xalan:xalan:2.7.1'
        dependency 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3'
        dependency 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.1'
        dependency 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
        dependency 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
        dependency 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.1'
        dependency 'org.mvel:mvel2:2.4.11.Final'
    }
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${SPRING_CLOUD}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:${SPRING_CLOUD_AWS}"
    }
    testCompile {
        dependencies {
            //dependency "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5"
        }
    }
}


allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
        }
    }
}

//apply from: 'gradle/code-quality.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/dependency-check.gradle'
//apply from: 'gradle/utils.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/dependency-updates.gradle'

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    //compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.4.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config'
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws"
    compile 'com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib'//:1.0.4' TODO Commented out
    //compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.792' TODO Commented out
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-events', version: '3.6.0'//'2.2.2'
    //implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1' TODO Commented out
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1' TODO Commented out
    //implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: '1.11.993' TODO Commented out

    //implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30' TODO Commented out
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c/dom
    implementation group: 'org.w3c', name: 'dom', version: '2.3.0'//-jaxb-1.0.6
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs
    //implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: '1.11.988'
    
    //implementation group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-core', version: '3.0.10.RELEASE' TODO Commented out
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version: '1.3'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
    //testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test' TODO Commented out
    
    runtimeOnly 'org.jlib:jlib-awslambda-logback:1.0.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'//Added to run tests in IDE

    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    compile 'xalan:xalan'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang'
    compile 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'

    //compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11' TODO Commented out
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    compile 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.1'
    compile 'org.mvel:mvel2:2.4.11.Final'
    
    //compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0' TODO Commented out
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1'
    //compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0' TODO Commented out
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator" TODO Commented out
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web" TODO Commented out

     testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0"))
        testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')
        testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params')
        testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine')
        testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '3.2.0'
        test.useJUnitPlatform() // fix "test events not received" bug in IDEA
        testCompile 'com.willowtreeapps.assertk:assertk-jvm:0.23'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.cam.cam.orch.handler.CamOrchFunction"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include '*'
     }
}

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
    doLast{
        FileTree tree = fileTree('build/distributions')
        tree.each {
            println it.name
        }
    }
}

test {

    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
    }
    reports.html.enabled = false
    reports.junitXml.enabled = true
}


task testReport {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'junitreport', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator', classpath: configurations.antJUnit.asPath)
    dependsOn subprojects*.test
    doFirst {
        mkdir "$buildDir/test-results"
        ant.junitreport(todir: "$buildDir/test-results") {
            subprojects.each {
                if (it.testResultsDir.exists()) {
                    fileset(dir: it.testResultsDir)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry, where's the detail on the error you encountered?  Thanks

Comment: Apologies I've added the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving away from the Old V1 API and replace it with the AWS SDK for Java V2. Amazon recommends using v2:

**The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**

The AWS SDK for Java V2 works fine with the Spring framework. There is a tutorial that shows use of the SQS service and Spring Framework. However - it uses a POM file not Gradle. However, it may help you.

[Creating an example messaging application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_message_application)

There are no end to end tutorials like this one for V1.

Comment: Thanks for recommending that. I'll make the change. For anyone who has the same issue I ran the command gradle dependencies and found that 2 sdk references were different than the rest. Making them all the same resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue I ran the command gradle dependencies and found that 2 sdk references were different than the rest. Making them all the same resolved the issue.